# Solving equations in C

Tags: c, equation-solving

I need to solve the following equation in C:

```
a + ln(a) = x
```

I know the value of x and I need to find the value of 'a' that satisfies this equation. Can anyone suggest an efficient method for solving this equation. May be Newton Raphson, or anything more efficient ?

Comment: This belongs on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's numerical methods, so SO should be fine.  Anything wrong with using N-R?

Comment: I need something more efficient, since this is for a real time calculation.

Answer (score 2):

`Newton Raphson Method` will do good but I suggest that you try out [`Lambert W function`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
W(x) = inverse of the function f(x)= xex.
So, in your case ln(a)+ a= x, then, taking the exponential of each side, eln(a)+ a= aea= ex.
This gives you `a=W(ex)`.
Now, you can apply approximations to solve this. But first, I suggest that you read about Lambert method carefully.